# If $B, B'$ and $C$ are $A$-algebras and $x\in B'$, then does it hold that $B[x]\otimes_A C\cong (B\otimes_A C)[x\otimes 1]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, commutative-algebra

(All rings are assumed to be commutative)

I'm trying to show that if $B'$ is integral over $B\subset B'$, then $B'\otimes_A C$ is integral over $B\otimes_A C$.

To this end, let $x\otimes y\in B'\otimes C$. Since $B[x]$ is a finitely-generated $B$-modules, $B[x]\otimes C$ is a finitely-generated $(B\otimes C)$-module. If the statement in the title were to hold, we could note that

$$B[x]\otimes C = B[x]\otimes C[y]\cong \left(B\otimes C[y]\right)[x\otimes 1]\cong (B\otimes C)[x\otimes 1, 1\otimes y].$$
Since $(B\otimes C)[x\otimes 1, 1\otimes y]$ is a finitely-generated $(B\otimes C)$-algebra containing $(B\otimes C)[x\otimes y]$, then $x\otimes y$ is integral over $B\otimes C$ and we're done.

However, I highly suspect that the statement in the title is false. If it were that $A = B$, then it would hold. But when trying to construct the obvious map
$$b_0 + \cdots + b_nx^n \otimes c \mapsto (b_0\otimes c)^0(x\otimes 1) + \cdots + (b_n\otimes c)(x\otimes 1)^n$$
in the general case, I noticed that it may not be injective. For example, if $s\in B$ and $c\in C$ are nonzero elements such that $s\otimes c = 0$, then for any element $f\in B[x]$ we'd have that $f\otimes c$ and $(sx^{\text{deg}(f)} + f)\otimes c$ have the same image under our map. More generally, if $S_c$ is the ideal of elements $s$ such that $s\otimes c = 0$, then the kernel of our map contains each $S_c[x]\otimes c$, meaning that this map is likely to have a large kernel.

This is why I expect that the statement is false, as the obvious map doesn't work. There may  be another less-obvious map that's an isomorphism, but I cannot think of one so I wanted to double check here.

Comment: $S_c[x]\otimes c$ is already zero in the left ring, so the obvious map may very well be injective

Comment: @vanxoo Ahh, I see this now. Thanks. I'm phenomenally bad at telling when objects are zero in a tensor product. But, due to John Doe's answer I realized my oversight that I only need the map to be surjective (which is obviously is) as its image will be finitely generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map doesn't have to be injective.  It's enough that it's surjective.  I'm not sure what you still need proven.

Do you agree there is a surjective map of rings
$$B[x]\otimes_A C \twoheadrightarrow (B\otimes_A C)[x\otimes 1_C]$$
sending $x$ to $x\otimes 1_C$, $B$ to $B\otimes 1_C$ and $C$ to $1_B\otimes C$?

Do you agree that this map is also a map of $B\otimes_A C$-modules because $1_B$ is the unit of $B[x]$ and the map sends $1_B\otimes 1_C$ to $1_B\otimes 1_C$?

Do you agree $B[x]\otimes_A C$ is a finitely-generated $B\otimes_A C$-module?

Do you agree that a homomorphic image of a finitely-generated module over a ring is a finitely generated module over the same ring?

So $(B\otimes_A C)[x\otimes 1_C]$ is a finitely-generated $B\otimes_A C$-module and $x\otimes y = (1_B\otimes y)(x\otimes 1_C)$ is in it so it's integral.

Notice however that you need to generalize for elements $\sum_j x_j \otimes y_j = \sum_j (1_B\otimes y_j)(x_j\otimes 1_C)$, so there is still work to be done for $B[x_1,\dots,x_k]$.  It's not enough to consider $B[x]$ for one element.